# winapinameA vs winapinameW - Unicode vs Ansi - Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, winapi, unicode, delphi-xe2, ansi

I am using Delphi XE2 and importing SHGetFolderPath from Shell32.dll. I am running windows vista x64. When running SHGetFolderPathA The result is unclear.

I.E.:

```
uses
  Windows;

function SHGetFolderPath(hwnd: Cardinal; csidl: Integer; hToken: Cardinal; dwFlags: Cardinal; pszPath: PChar): Cardinal; stdcall;external 'Shell32.dll' name 'SHGetFolderPathA';

Var
  Path:Array [0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  AppData:String;

begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0,$001A,0,0,@path[0]);
  MessageBox(0,Path,'a',0);
end.
```

The result is:

[image]

Versus using SHGetFolderPathW:

uses
      Windows;

```
function SHGetFolderPath(hwnd: Cardinal; csidl: Integer; hToken: Cardinal; dwFlags: Cardinal; pszPath: PChar): Cardinal; stdcall;external 'Shell32.dll' name 'SHGetFolderPathW';

Var
  Path:Array [0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  AppData:String;

begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0,$001A,0,0,@path[0]);
  MessageBox(0,Path,'a',0);
end.
```

The result clearly states the path to my AppData folder with no issue.

When running this same code on x32 Vista when using SHGetFolderPathA works just fine.

If someone could shine some light on why this is? I was under the impression the "W" api was usually for use on Unicode machines...?

---

Edit:

I am now using the following code, with the same error:

```
uses
  Windows;

function SHGetFolderPath(hwnd: HWND; csidl: Integer; hToken: THandle; dwFlags: DWord; pszPath: PAnsiChar): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'SHFolder.dll' name 'SHGetFolderPathA';

var
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0,$001A,0,0, @path[0]);
  MessageBox(0,path,'a',0);
end.
```

---

Final Edit:

Thank you all for the responses. The above declaration of SHGetFolderPath is fine. After looking through all responses, and taking in the information in each, I have come up with the following result:

```
uses
  Windows;

function SHGetFolderPath(hwnd: HWND; csidl: Integer; hToken: THandle; dwFlags: DWord; pszPath: PAnsiChar): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll' name 'SHGetFolderPathA';

var
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of ansichar;
  xRes:String;
begin
  If SHGetFolderPath(0,$001A,0,0, @path[0]) = S_OK Then Begin
    xRes := Path;
    MessageBox(0,PWideChar(xRes),'Result',0);
  End Else
    MessageBox(0,'An error has occurred.','Result',0);
end.
```

The resulting messagebox correctly displays the path to my AppData path.

Thanks again for all of the responses.

Comment: That code behaves the same on x32 Vista as it does on x64 Vista. I'll bet you have a non Unicode Delphi installed on the x32 machine.

Comment: Why are you defining SHGetFolderPath yourself. Surely it's right there in the VCL.

Comment: My top tip is to enable the typed address operator compiler option. Then your code won't compile until it is correct.

Comment: I think you need to read up on Unicode. Look for Marco Cantu's whitepaper on the subject and read that before you continue.

Comment: The `SHGetFolderPath` is already defined in two units, `Winapi.SHFolder` and `Winapi.ShlObj`.

Comment: Your final edit is bizarre. You haven't really listened to the responses. Don't define SHGetFolderPath. Use the definition included in Delphi libraries. And why do you feel the need to use ANSI buffers at all? Why are you converting from ANSI to UTF-16 in the xRes assignment? I don't think you are anywhere near understanding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared the final parameter of `SHGetFolderPath` as having type `PChar`. In Delphi 2009 and later (which includes your version, Delphi XE2), `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar`, yet you told Delphi to link your declared function to the "A" version, which expects `AnsiChar` characters.

When declaring functions that are sensitive to the character type, I recommend not using `PChar` at all. Explicitly use either `PWideChar` or `PAnsiChar`.

The "A" and "W" suffixes aren't about which kind of *machine* the program runs on. *All* supported versions of Windows are Unicode now — the last non-Unicode version was Windows ME. The "A" and "W" refer to the character type of the arguments.

As for why your code worked on the 32-bit version of Vista when it fails on the 64-bit version, I have no explanation. Maybe you're just lucky and the OS did some conversions that happened to work out OK in your case.

Comment: It seems I may have accepted your answer prematurely. After changing the last declaration from PChar to PAnsiChar, the issue remains the same. I have tried all conversions, including the declaration type of the variable "path". Nothing is changing the result, it is just the same.

Comment: No, you did not accept prematurely. Stop using Char. Use AnsiChar for A functions, WideChar for W functions.

Comment: MessageBox will be the Unicode version too -- once you get Path populated with AnsiChars you need to convert it to Unicode.  AppData := string(path);  or use MessageBoxA(0, Path, 'a', 0);

Comment: And make sure you are specifying the correct function name - A or W - in the `external` declaration to match the parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

`Char` is Unicode in XE2, but you are importing the Ansi version of `SHGetFolderPath()` and passing a Unicode output buffer to it.  That is why your `MessageBox()` is displaying garbage - it is trying to display Ansi data in a Unicode dialog box.  You need to import the Unicode version of `SHGetFolderPath()` instead:

```
uses
  Windows;

function SHGetFolderPath(hwnd: HWND; csidl: Integer; hToken: THandle; dwFlags: DWord; pszPath: PWideChar): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'SHFolder.dll' name 'SHGetFolderPathW';

var
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0, $001A, 0, 0, path);
  MessageBox(0, path,'a', 0);
end.
```

BTW, XE2 already imports both Ansi and Unicode versions of `SHGetFolderPath()` for you, as well as defined the CSIDL values, so you do not need to do it manually:

```
uses
  Windows, ShlObj, SHFolder;

var
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, 0, path);
  MessageBox(0, path, 'a', 0);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see <del>two mistakes</del> one mistake:

<del>- "Path" is declared as local variable (i.e. on the Stack) so it contains "random"/stale data. It is recommended to initialize it with zeroes: fillChar(path[0], sizeOf(path), #0)</del>

- SHGetFolderPath is a function. It returns a value. You never test function's result to see if it secceeded or not - you just output the contents of the "path" variable. But are the contents meaningful if SHGetFolderPath had failed for some reason?

Comment: Your point 1 is incorrect. It's an out buffer. Initializing is pointless.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're right! But it can partially explain the strange chars in the screenshot if SHGetFolderPath has failed :) Thanks!

Comment: The remaining point is fair, but the function returns no error. Because as far as the API is, it worked fine. The API function can't tell that the caller is interpreting 8 bit text as if it were UTF-16. Whenever you treat 8 bit text as UTF-16, it looks like that. We've done this a million times before on SO.